# Doctrine 2 new entities on iterate update

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, batch-processing

I´m currently having issues, I´m trying to do a batch script, it´s about contracts, invoices and invoice items. If one contract is on due date, must create a new invoice and move contract date.

So, create invoice and its items works properly. Problem itself on update contract, it doesn´t update new contract values.

Please look, this is my code

```
    public function makeinvoicesAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    // Make sure that we are running in a console and the user has not tricked our
    // application into running this action from a public web server.
    if (!$request instanceof ConsoleRequest){
        throw new \RuntimeException('You can only use this action from a console!');
    }
    $verbose = $request->getParam('verbose') || $request->getParam('v');
    if ($verbose) echo "Iniciado el proceso de facturacion";

    $today = new \DateTime();

    $cInvoices = 0;
    $months    = 0;

    $dql    = "SELECT i.number FROM Billing\Entity\Invoice i ORDER BY i.number DESC";
    $query  = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
    $query->setMaxResults(1);
    $result = $query->getArrayResult();
    $numInvoice = intval($result[0]['number']) + 1;

    $dql       = sprintf("SELECT c FROM Customer\Entity\Contract c WHERE c.dueDate = '%s' AND c.status = '%d' AND c.enableInvoicing = true", $today->format('Y-m-d'), \Customer\Entity\Contract::STATUS_ACTIVE);
    $query     = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
    $contracts = $query->iterate();

    foreach ($contracts as $row) {
        $contract    = $row[0];
        $tax         = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Setup\Entity\Tax', 1);
        $invoice     = new \Billing\Entity\Invoice();
        $invoiceItem = new \Billing\Entity\InvoiceItem();

        //Calcs for item
        $invoiceItem->type = \Billing\Entity\InvoiceItem::TYPE_SERVICE;
        $invoiceItem->description = $contract->product->name;
        $invoiceItem->quantity = 1;
        switch ($contract->invoiceFrecuency) {
            case \Customer\Entity\Contract::FRECUENCY_MONTHLY:
                $invoiceItem->unitPrice = $contract->product->priceMonthly;
                $months = 1;
                break;
            case \Customer\Entity\Contract::FRECUENCY_QUARTERLY:
                $invoiceItem->unitPrice = $contract->product->priceQuarterly;
                $months = 3;
                break;
            case \Customer\Entity\Contract::FRECUENCY_ANNUAL:
                $invoiceItem->unitPrice = $contract->product->priceAnnual;
                $months = 12;
                break;
            case \Customer\Entity\Contract::FRECUENCY_BIANNUAL:
                $invoiceItem->unitPrice = $contract->product->priceBiannual;
                $months = 24;
                break;
            default:
                continue;
                break;
        }
        $invoiceItem->amount = ($invoiceItem->quantity * $invoiceItem->unitPrice) / (1 + $tax->rate);
        $invoiceItem->taxAmount = $invoiceItem->amount * $tax->rate;
        $invoiceItem->tax = $tax;
        $invoiceItem->product = $contract->product;
        $invoiceItem->invoice = $invoice;
        $invoiceItem->tsCreated = new \DateTime('now');

        //Creation of new invoice
        $today = new \DateTime('now');
        $invoice->date = new \DateTime('now');
        $invoice->dueDate = $today->add(new \DateInterval('P'. $contract->product->dueDayFirst .'D'));
        $invoice->number  = $numInvoice;
        $invoice->credit = 0;
        $invoice->status = \Billing\Entity\Invoice::STATUS_UNPAID;
        $invoice->addItem($invoiceItem);
        $invoice->contract = $contract;
        $invoice->tsCreated = new \DateTime('now');

        //Update contract
        $contract->dueDate->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $months . 'M'));

        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($invoice);
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($invoiceItem);
        if (($cInvoices % self::BATCH_SIZE) === 0) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
            $this->getEntityManager()->clear();
        }
        ++$cInvoices;
        ++$numInvoice;
    }
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
    $this->getservicelocator()->get('Logger')->info('Creadas ' . $cInvoices . ' facturas');
    if ($verbose) echo "\nCreadas $cInvoices facturas\nFinalizado el proceso\n";
}
```

What I´m doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

David L.

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist the contract to the entityManager.

```
$this->getEntityManager()->persist($contract);
```

Comment: Hi Bram, I update but still without update contracts, it makes invoices but doesn´t update contract. Thanks.